# How does this C copy function exit its loop?

Tags: c

```
void copy (char *source, char *dest) {
    while (*dest++ = *source++);
}
```

The char that is represented by `*source` is copied to the field `*dest` points to. For the next iteration, each char pointer points to the next field in memory, is that correct?

When does this loop actually stop? The only condition I can think of is that there's no space left in memory, but then the function must terminate with an error, shouldn't it?

I'm completely new to C, so forgive me the simple questions.

Comment: when it hits a null terminating char - `0`.

Comment: The char `\0` is implicitly convertible to the int `0` which is considered `false`. An expression of type `a = b` evaluates to `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char`s are integral types. Integral types are interpreted as conditionals in the following way:

```
 0 -> false
 Anything else -> true
```

Since "strings" in C are null-terminated (meaning `0` or `'\0'`) when it reaches the end of the string it stops.

Comment: Your equivalent loop is not equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I think it may just be confusing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The 'result' of an assignment is the right-hand value. So `x=1;` actually *returns* a value; in this case, '1'.

Your code copies characters until it encountered the terminating 0 at the end of the `source` string.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the copy is correct. The loop stops when what dest is pointing to is zero, i.e., the '\0' character. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string